# Is this an issue in giving reputations?

Tags: discussion, reputation

W.K.T, when a user got a downvote for his posts before getting any reputations will not get any negative reputations.

So, after getting positive reputations, the user should get his penalty(-2) since his/her reputations can get substracted to get a positive number.

But, it doesn't happen like that in SO.
for ex, take this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807272/consider-this-code-int-s-20-int-t-s-s-what-are-the-values-of-s-a), it got 3 downvotes and 3 upvotes and see the user's reputations.

Is this an issue or the fact of SO.

Comment: It's by design.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good find. The title and wording made it fairly difficult to find, for me. Not *quite* a duplicate IMHO though (it handles the "user at 1 rep, gets downvote, what happens"-case), even if one of the answers would answer this. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: I just happened to remember having seen something like this before.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That seems to be the case with most duplicate-identifications. Meta users are rather... active, I find. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: The last time I tried to escape, they gave me the hose. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only lose reputation that you've **first gained**, so you first need to gain reputation. Everything, with some exceptions, happens according to a timeline.