# 'Hi' appears in question body but not in edit box or preview. Has it been auto-trimmed?

Tags: support, edits, quality-filter

[Changing the interval of an NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080873/changing-the-interval-of-a-nstimer) over on Stack Overflow starts with the word "Hi" (at the moment, anyways):

[image]

After I click the edit link, there is no evidence of "Hi" in either the edit field or preview:

[image]

I've refreshed the page approximately seventeen times, just to make sure no-one edited it while it was open in a background tab. Is the word "Hi" being [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/159251) at the time of *editing*, or am I and my computer both going crazy? The question is older than that post of Jeff's, so the "Hi" wouldn't have been subject to removal at posting. Any further details about this auto-trimming, if indeed that's what this is?

Comment: It just disappeared!

Comment: You missed the bit at the end of his answer: "I've also removed most of the salutations (per above) across the network from existing posts."

Comment: I just edited it. `Hi` and stuffs are actually trimmed in the source, but probably not updated to the HTML.

Comment: @TimStone: I saw the bit at the end, but I didn't know about the part where it was pre-rendered. Thanks for the dupe! I figured this had been reported before, but I just couldn't find it.

Comment: I was planning on editing it after I figured out what was going on, @nhahtdh, in case there _was_ a bug of some kind.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. And no problem, it's a fairly obscure issue to search for, I just had the benefit of knowing it existed and where to find it, heh.

Comment: @TimStone: That's how [it always is here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167091/is-this-an-issue-in-giving-reputations#comment489787_167091)!